# Do company benefits, such as HSA or pre-tax commuter plans, that open up accounts in my name affect my credit report or score?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-report, benefits

My company offers a couple different benefit plans that provide me with an account where funds get added and I can charge expenses to.  For example, I now have an account and a debit card with a bank for my HSA that the company opened up in my name.  And now I am going to get another one with for pre-tax commuter funds with a different bank.

Do these types of accounts that companies open up as part of their employee benefit programs affect my report or score in any way?  For example, since they are in my name I assume they are yet another account I have to monitor on my report.  And that to open them the bank had to do a pull.  If these accounts are opened frequently enough, would that ding my score?

Comment: I'm not aware of HSA or similar employer-sponsered benefit accounts ever being opened as *credit* accounts.  A savings account (whatever the methods of and restrictions upon withdrawals) should not affect credit score.

Answer (score 4):

Only credit accounts should make it into your ratings - accounts where there is a chance that you borrow or owe money and not pay it (back).

I have multiple such accounts for many years, and none of them is ever listed at the credit reporting agencies. Even my company travel expense credit card is never a showing there.

I don't have a hard proof, but I think the answer is no, they're not.

Comment: Many years ago my "company travel card" did show up in my credit report. I had a co-worker who had to scramble to get proof that it was a company card, and that he wasn't hiding it. The final credit check for his mortgage found the new card even before the company mailed it to him. The use of employees credit history was so unpopular most employees ended up rejecting the cards.

Answer (score 0):

HSAs and other "defined benefit" accounts CAN end up showing up as accounts on your credit report, depending on how they're administered, but they are not credit accounts, so do not come into play for your FICO (or other) credit score.

Comment: Any references or other proof for this? I had an HSA for 2 years, and it's not on any of my reports.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, I imagine it depends on how the account is administered.  My FSA and HSA show up on my Experian report as "open accounts" alongside my checking accounts, probably because of how the benefits plan is administered.

Comment: OK, not to be too pedantic, your DO should be a CAN. Because they don't always. I'd +1 answer if you edit that.

Comment: @dwoz, an FSA is both not a checking account and not an individual account, and none of my checking accounts have ever appeared on my credit report.  I just looked at my Experian report, none of my checking accounts, my current HSA, and my prior HSAs all aren't listed.  I'm not going to give you a minus 1, but I've never heard of an FSA appearing on a credit report and I can't come up with a scenario where it could be reported, don't believe you that an FSA appears on your Experian report (ignoring the fact that you generally can't contribute to an HSA and an FSA at the same time).

Comment: @quid, I've not got much to say beyond that it is possible in certain circumstances to have both an HSA and FSA, but it's not a common scenario.  My experience with these both was from two different years.  The report that they show up on is the full report available to creditors, which is different than the "free" report you see as a consumer.  Lots of stuff shows up on those reports that have nothing much to do with FICO scores.  I'm also NOT suggesting that all defined benefit accounts make it to your credit report.

Comment: I checked my report from the paid credit monitoring service not the free one.  You can only contribute to both if the FSA reimbursements are limited such that they exclude medical expenses unrelated to dental and vision care.  And again, I've never heard of an FSA being reported, it's not possible for an FSA to roll negative. I have no idea what you were looking at that would include checking accounts and HSA & FSA accounts.  Perhaps it's some sort of identity monitoring, but they're not credit report items, unless you can provide any sort of evidence to support what you're claiming.

Comment: @quid, I believe I keep saying that they are not credit report items, such as when I said "...lots of stuff shows up on those reports that have nothing much to do with FICO scores..." and "...but they are not credit accounts, so do not come into play for your FICO (or other) credit score...."   Did you miss those statements?

Comment: Then maybe you missed the point of the question "affect my credit report or score?"  And perhaps then you shouldn't claim they "can appear on your credit report" in your answer if you don't mean credit report.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is only one way for any of these to show up on your credit.  If you open an HSA account, then somehow run it empty, and are in a situation were you owe a monthly maintenance fee that goes delinquent, you may see collection attempts on the delinquent fee that could show up on your credit.

This would exclusively impact HSA savings accounts.  An employer can sponsor as HSA eligible High Deductible Health Plan (HDHPs) but the associated HSA account is an individual account.  Your employer, or the insurance carrier, may have a preferred financial institution that usually carries a preferred fee structure to the employees.  Ultimately this is an individual account so if you leave your employer or if your employer changes carriers or HSA vendor recommendations you may owe a maintenance fee to continue the prior account.  I've never heard of an HSA account running negative, but I suppose it's possible and if it happens it could cause collections efforts and a credit ding.

FSAs and the like are fully employer money arrangements and due to the IRS regulations surrounding them it's not possible to owe money.